# Custom GWT fileUpload Button

Tags: button, gwt, file-upload

Good Day
I need to make a button which would upload files. Now I have used fileUploader but it is in label form, have name (Browse...) and another things that I do not need. Is any possibility to give to GWT Button functions of FileUploader

Answer (score 0):

I made a FileUploader widget transparent and put it above an icon. You can put it above a button instead, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) library which comes with a [DecoratedFileUpload](https://gwtupload.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/website/javadoc/library/gwtupload/client/DecoratedFileUpload.html) widget which you can customise. You can see how they look in this [demo](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/gwtuploadsample.SingleUploadSample/SingleUploadSample.html). It uses different approaches depending on the browser because of different issues, like browsers not supporting to call the `click()` method due to security issues, etc.